# Creating a 'shutting down' window for a closing application

Tags: c++, winapi

I am relatively new to C++ programming and currently using Visual Studio 2012 API. My OS is Windows 7 64-bit. I would like to write a program in C++ which displays a message box or window with a simple shutdown message e.g. 'shutting down.....' or something similar when I close a specific application. This window I am hoping will appear for the duration of the app exit time and then close.

Is it possible to create a handle which will retrieve the exit time for a running application when it is abruptly closed? And if so, how could I use this exit time in a statement which will display the message box?

I would appreciate constructive criticism as I am new to this language. Thank you sincerely for any advice you impart. If requested, I will display all source code.

I don't think this is the right way to go about this but anyway, below is a snippet of the code which I have been toying with, as part of a greater VS Win32 application project:

```
LPTSTR  lpchText(_T("Shutting down...."));
   LPFILETIME lpExitTime = 0; //Initialise
   TCHAR Buffer[_MAX_PATH];
   DWORD size = _MAX_PATH;
   LPCTSTR lpStr(_T("C:\Program Files\Common Files\ExampleApp.exe")); // Path to executable app.



   AssocQueryString(    ASSOCF_OPEN_BYEXENAME,
                        ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE,
                        lpStr,
                        NULL,
                        Buffer,
                        &size
                        );

   GetProcessTimes(
                        AssocQueryString,
                        NULL,
                        lpExitTime,
                        NULL,
                        NULL
                 );

   while(lpExitTime){


                        MessageBoxEx(
                        _In_opt_  hWnd,
                        _In_opt_  lpchText,
                        _In_opt_  lpCaption,
                        _In_opt_  MB_ICONEXCLAMATION
                        ,0
                        ); 

                   };
  return TRUE; 

    enter code here
```

Comment: How are you going to detect that this external process is about to close down? Are you in control of this external process? You appear to have started coding before having really worked out what to code. That is usually a mistake.

Comment: Yes, the application will be closed by myself! But I would like to know how to connect to this process via the source code?? Any ideas?? I feel that the path to the executable application is not enough....I need a real-time connection..

Comment: I really have no idea what you are getting at. Never mind. Perhaps somebody else understands.

Answer (score 1):

I guess shutting down the application is a lengthy operation othervise a normal application will be closed so fast that the user will have no chance to actual see the window.

But of course it possible, in meta code this is the steps.

1. Attach to the running process. You can enumrate the running process from the name of the executable to find the correct process.
2. Once you have the handle to the process you can attach to the process message loop.
3. Listen for the WM_QUIT (assuming it is a Windows applictaion) message and then display the window.
4. Wait for the process handle using MsgWaitForMultipleObject, the function will signal when the process terminates.

Attaching to other processes has some security issues so it might not work for a regular user.

Other options to explore is to handle it in a power Shell script or make a small launcher application that in turn starts the actual application.

Is it an option to modify the application itself to have this functionality?

Comment: Yes, but the application I am working with usually takes between 3 - 5 seconds to close completely....No the application is not to be modified. I am simply looking to alert a potential user that the app is shutting down via the message box... But I think your steps will help me achieve this...thanks